# Webpack and TypeScript - no transpilation and missing code

Tags: typescript, webpack

This is driving me insane.

I've got a pretty simple webpack/typescript setup but for some reason in the output bundle there is no transpilation down to ES5 and modules are not included in the bundle.

The even more annoying thing is that I've got another project with exactly the same setup that works correctly.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './lib/main.ts',
    output: {
        filename: './assets/js/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts']
    },
    modules: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

### main.ts

```
import { thing } from './thing';
console.log(thing.foo);
```

### thing.ts

```
export const thing = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

### bundle.js

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    import { thing } from './thing';
    console.log(thing.foo);

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Comment: Could you put the repo up on github?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after looking again with a clear head.

My webpack.config.js had a **modules** property rather than a **module** property.

Damn you fat fingers!